# Recovering x-axis value on click - NVD3 LineChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

**Is there any way to recover the x axis value on click event in the `lineChart()` of NVD3?**

The closest I get is by this answer: [nvd3.js : unable to bind onClick event with the data points in the svg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16103244/2394172)

But what I want is to recover the x axis value and redirect to another page, passing it as parameter.

I tried this approach too, similar as one that I use on multiBarChart, but unsuccessful:

```
$("g.nv-point-paths").on("hover", function (d) {
    $("path").off("click");
    $("path").on("click", function (d) {
        //do something with 'd'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it by myself, by debugging the javascript of the page:

```
$("g.nv-point-paths").on("hover", function (d) {
    $("g.nv-point-paths path").off("click");
    $("g.nv-point-paths path").on("click", function (d) {
        var xAxisValue = d.currentTarget.__data__.data.point[4].x;
    });
});
```

If someone have a better solution to this, please answer here.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using the following:

```
chart.lines.dispatch.on('elementClick', function(e) { ... }
```

The `e` variable has everything you need inside of it. Just set a breakpoint and inspect the `e` var to see how to access whatever you want.

Example:

```
chart.lines.dispatch.on('elementClick', function(e) {
alert(e.point.label);
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea how to get those details from the focus area? would you please check this request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138480/get-last-updated-brush-states-issue