# get last updated brush states issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I looked every where and I tried several solution but I wasn't able to find something similar to `brushend` in angular-nvd3 lineWithFocusChart.
in fact I'm trying to get the details of the rendered brush extent.
I tried

```
callback : function(chart) {
            chart.focus.dispatch.on('brush', function(e) {
                console.log("hello", e)
            });
        }
```

But it renders all details and not the last one and when I use 'brushend' i get an error message like if the dispatch is undefined `d3.js:492 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`.
Can you please help me :(

Comment: This seems their open issue https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/138

Comment: @sandyJoshi that's the same issue and it seems that was not update since August 2015 :( there is nothing for brushend events for charts with zoom